# Recommended SP/method to gain information

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I need more information about table and its column I always use the build-in stored procedure 'sp_help xxxxx' to retrieve more information.

What other method or SP are usable to use?

Comment: What information are you looking for?

Comment: As per @RedFilter - what are you looking for?  As well as the answers already provided sp_helptext gives you the text of the proc

Comment: I want to retrieve so much information as possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sp_depends to get want tables and columns it is using

```
EXEC sp_depends yourProcedure;
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use dynamic management views (DMV) and functions (DMF) to get more information about database server..........The DMV/DMF's have been organized into the following different groups:

```
Common Language Runtime related
Database Mirroring related
Execution related
Full-Text Search related
Index related
I/O related
Query Notifications related
Replication related
Service Broker related
SQL Server Operation system
Transaction related
```

Comment: To help the OP...  `And these are?  Or can be utilised how?`

Answer (score 0):

Just browsing to the table in SQL Server Management Studio will tell you quite a lot.

- Table/Column definitions.
- Indexes
- Triggers
- Constraints
- Primary/Foreign Keys
- Dependancies
- etc, etc

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `sysobjects` view (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'P'
```

Other sys view can be handy too.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [sp_columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176077.aspx)

```
EXEC sp_columns @table_name = N'TableName'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sp_helptext will come in handy, it gives you the definition of a stored procedure, function or view.

I.E.:

```
CREATE PROC usp_MyProcedure AS SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

Runing the following will output the query above.

```
Exec sp_helptext 'usp_MyProcedure'
```